# How to merge pandas dataframe without creating multiple duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in pandas I wish to merge, which I can do using the following line `data_cords = data_0_0.merge(data, on= "unique_id", how = "left")` I get the desired result in terms of all the variables I want together are present in the data_cords df.

The problem is my method creates many exact duplicate rows. To get my desired end product I use `df = data_cords.drop_duplicates()` but all of this is very expensive memory wise which is an issue as I run the code on google colab. Is there a way I can do the merge without creating all the duplicate rows?

I have inserted screenshots of ach dataframe to the end of the question to add clarity. apologies if this is the incorrect format I am relatively new here.

df data_0_0 looks like this:
[image]

& df data looks like this:
[image]

df data_cords ends up like this like this with the desired columns added to the end of each sequence:
[image]

Comment: It is difficult to suggest without looking at the data (at least partially). Did you try other kinds of merge? Like ``how='inner'``?

Comment: @MaximIvanov I have added some screen shots for clarity. To answer your question yes I did but I couldn't get it to work and my method was fine when I was just using a small subsample of my data but now it has this obvious drawback.

Comment: can you replace the image with clear text data?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer in this earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58036174/eliminating-duplicates-based-on-conditions-in-data-frame?noredirect=1&lq=1)

For my particular code the solution is to run `data.drop_duplicates()` before `running data_cords = data_0_0.merge(data, on= "unique_id", how = "left")`