# Drop Duplicates based on Nearest Datetime condition

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

```
import pandas as pd

def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Files/input.txt", dtype=str)
duplicatesDf = df[df.duplicated(subset=['CLASS_ID', 'START_TIME', 'TEACHER_ID'], keep=False)]
duplicatesDf['START_TIME'] =  pd.to_datetime(duplicatesDf['START_TIME'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print duplicatesDf
print df['START_TIME'].dt.date

df:
ID,CLASS_ID,START_TIME,TEACHER_ID,END_TIME
1,123,2020/06/01 20:47:26.000,o1,2020/06/02 00:00:00.000
2,123,2020/06/01 20:47:26.000,o1,2020/06/04 20:47:26.000
3,789,2020/06/01 20:47:26.000,o3,2020/06/03 14:47:26.000
4,789,2020/06/01 20:47:26.000,o3,2020/06/03 14:40:00.000
5,456,2020/06/01 20:47:26.000,o5,2020/06/08 20:00:26.000
```

So, I've got a dataframe like mentioned above. As you can see, I have multiple records with the same `CLASS_ID,START_DATE` and `TEACHER_ID`. Whenever, multiple records like these are present, I would like to retain only 1 record based on the condition that, **the retained record should have its `END_DATE` nearest to its `START_DATE`(by minute level precision)**.

In this case,
 for `CLASS_ID 123`, the record with `ID 1` will be retained, as its `END_DATE 2020/06/02 00:00:00.000` is nearest to its `START_DATE 2020/06/01 20:47:26.000` as compared to record with `ID 2` whose `END_DATE is 2020/06/04 20:47:26.000`. Similarly for `CLASS_ID 789`, record with `ID 4` will be retained.

Hence the expected output will be:

```
ID,CLASS_ID,START_TIME,TEACHER_ID,END_TIME
1,123,2020/06/01 20:47:26.000,o1,2020/06/02 00:00:00.000
4,789,2020/06/01 20:47:26.000,o3,2020/06/03 14:40:00.000
5,456,2020/06/01 20:47:26.000,o5,2020/06/08 20:00:26.000
```

I've been going through the following links,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32237949,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33043374
to find a solution but have unfortunately reached an impasse.

Hence, would some kind soul mind helping me out a bit. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, we can use `.loc` and `idxmin()` after creating a condtional column to measure the elapsed time between the start and the end, we will apply `idxmin()` as a groupby operation on your `CLASS_ID` column.

```
df.loc[
    df.assign(mins=(df["END_TIME"] - df["START_TIME"]))
    .groupby("CLASS_ID")["mins"]
    .idxmin()
]


   ID  CLASS_ID          START_TIME TEACHER_ID            END_TIME
0   1       123 2020-06-01 20:47:26         o1 2020-06-02 00:00:00
4   5       456 2020-06-01 20:47:26         o5 2020-06-08 20:00:26
3   4       789 2020-06-01 20:47:26         o3 2020-06-03 14:40:00
```

in steps.

## Time Delta.

```
print(df.assign(mins=(df["END_TIME"] - df["START_TIME"]))[['CLASS_ID','mins']])

   CLASS_ID            mins
0       123 0 days 03:12:34
1       123 3 days 00:00:00
2       789 1 days 18:00:00
3       789 1 days 17:52:34
4       456 6 days 23:13:00
```

minimum index from time delta column whilst grouping with `CLASS_ID`

```
print(df.assign(mins=(df["END_TIME"] - df["START_TIME"]) )
    .groupby("CLASS_ID")["mins"]
    .idxmin())

CLASS_ID
123    0
456    4
789    3
Name: mins, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Would you mind helping me in casting the timestamp columns in my dataframe from string to datetime? I need to read the whole file as a string as I'm doing further processings in the middle.

Comment: @Aron do you mean `df['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'])`?

Comment: yes. unfortunately its throwing a warning. Something like `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: did you copy your dataframe from another dataframe ? use `new_df = df.copy()` when copying to a new variable

Comment: No. I'm directly reading to the dataframe from the file. Then when I execute the `to_datetime` command, I get this warning

Comment: strange, instead in your read method, pass in `parse_dates` i.e `pd.read_csv(...,parse_dates=['START_TIME','END_TIME'])` @Aron

Comment: @Aron you are very welcome my friend, good luck in your analysis