# How to remove duplicates conditionally in this pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
columns = ['Date', 'Description', 'Original Description', 'Amount',
   'Transaction Type', 'Category', 'Account Name']
data =[['2023-07-31', 'HOUSTON METHODIST BILLNG',
    'HOUSTON METHODIST BILLNG', 6208.8, 'debit', 'Medical',
    'Chase Freedom'],
   ['2023-08-01', 'HOUSTON METHODIST BILLNG',
    'HOUSTON METHODIST BILLNG', 6208.8, 'debit', 'Medical',
    'Chase Freedom'],
   ['2023-12-01', 'Hilton Mar Caribe Cancún',
    'AplPay HILTON MAR CABENITO JUAREZ ME', 2314.55, 'debit',
    'Travel & Vacation', 'Amex EveryDay® Card'],
   ['2023-11-30', 'HILTON MAR CARIBE USD', 'HILTON MAR CARIBE USD',
    2314.55, 'debit', 'Travel & Vacation', 'Amex EveryDay® Card'],
   ['2023-09-29', 'STATE FARM INSURANCEBLOOMINGTON IL',
    'STATE FARM INSURANCEBLOOMINGTON IL', 462.54, 'debit',
    'Bills & Utilities', 'Amex EveryDay® Card'],
   ['2023-10-31', 'STATE FARM INSURANCEBLOOMINGTON IL',
    'STATE FARM INSURANCEBLOOMINGTON IL', 462.54, 'debit',
    'Bills & Utilities', 'Amex EveryDay® Card'],
   ['2023-11-29', 'STATE FARM INSURANCE', 'STATE FARM INSURANCE',
    462.54, 'debit', 'Bills & Utilities', 'Amex EveryDay® Card'],
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

In the above sample dataframe, rows 0,1 & 2,3 are duplicates but rest of them are not. I tried removing the duplicates by using *Amount* column but that removes other non duplicate same amount transactions. The logic I'm unable to implement is to remove the duplicate transaction by looking the same amount transaction happening with in one day of each other. I believe the duplicated transactions got created because of **actual transaction date** and **posted transaction date** for the same transaction.

Comment: "I tried ..."   Please share the code that you tried this with....

Comment: see: [Removing duplicates from Pandas dataFrame with condition for retaining original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042777/removing-duplicates-from-pandas-dataframe-with-condition-for-retaining-original)

Comment: Indeed as suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78179038/12846804, preventing the confusion between both kind of dates, **beforehand**, should be a priority. One first obvious measure could be that dates from both tables do not land into the same confused 'Date' column. Guessing which is which after the merge, as you probably agree, is poor practice and error prone.  I assumed that problem comes from merging 2 tables but I might be mistaken. Your assumption of 1 day maximum interval is probably a human arbitrary approximation; how could you be sure, in the future?

Answer (score 1):

You can drop duplicates by `Amount` only where the difference between the `Date` in the next row is 1 or less.

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df.loc[(df["Date"] - df.shift()["Date"]).abs() <= pd.Timedelta(days=1)] = (
    df.drop_duplicates("Amount")
)
df = df.dropna()
```

```
        Date                         Description                  Original Description  ...  Transaction Type           Category         Account Name
0 2023-07-31            HOUSTON METHODIST BILLNG              HOUSTON METHODIST BILLNG  ...             debit            Medical        Chase Freedom
2 2023-12-01            Hilton Mar Caribe Cancún  AplPay HILTON MAR CABENITO JUAREZ ME  ...             debit  Travel & Vacation  Amex EveryDay® Card
4 2023-09-29  STATE FARM INSURANCEBLOOMINGTON IL    STATE FARM INSURANCEBLOOMINGTON IL  ...             debit  Bills & Utilities  Amex EveryDay® Card
5 2023-10-31  STATE FARM INSURANCEBLOOMINGTON IL    STATE FARM INSURANCEBLOOMINGTON IL  ...             debit  Bills & Utilities  Amex EveryDay® Card
6 2023-11-29                STATE FARM INSURANCE                  STATE FARM INSURANCE  ...             debit  Bills & Utilities  Amex EveryDay® Card
```

This is not an ideal approach, as there may be actual transactions that just happen to have the same amount within 1 day, and they would be removed incorrectly. Seeing as the transactions don't have any kind of ID, I guess the best you could do is add other columns as argument to `drop_duplicates`, like `drop_duplicates(["Amount", "Transaction Type", "Category"])`.

Comment: Wise trick! however by only checking the date diff with the previous row, this method asusmes that duplicates will always be next to each other in the initial dataframe. Are we certain no entry could be inserted in between 2 dupes? Try you method on `df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42)`. Both `Hilton Mar Caribe Cancún` and `HILTON MAR CARIBE USD` rows will stay, while `STATE FARM INSURANCE` will be accidentally removed.

Comment: @OCa I assumed there wouldn't be an entry between duplicates based on the description of the problem and the data set, but you raise a good point. Calling `df = df.sort_values(["Date", "Amount"])` before filtering would solve that.

Comment: Surprisingly I kept coming back to this answer as it was puzzling me. Another failed verification: Set all dates equal. The outcome is far from the expected output. 3 rows remain instead of the expected 5. I feel OP should be warned that **this solution holds for the specific example given here, yet does not generalize well**. Especially in the case of multiple unrelated entries all within one day of each other, which should probably be anticipated.

Comment: @OCa Agreed, that's the last paragraph in my answer. If we set all dates equal, indices 4, 5 and 6 are considered duplicates. We'd probably want to keep 2 of them (so 4 in total). Or maybe there could be 3 duplicates for the same date, in which case the result is correct. In any case, there isn't really an ideal way of solving this with the provided data set. We haven't heard back from OP, so I'm not too worried about this question anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the engaging discussion. This data was sampled from the mint transactions download, I don't know what could be done at the source level. Surprisingly, the data doesn't have these issues on their UI. There's definitely something incorrect with export data functionality.  @e-motta I will definitely try out your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a source data than a processing issue. You need to identify a pattern, how you can identify your "duplicated" entries in the first place.

In your elaboration, you already refer to *"the duplicated transactions got created because of actual transaction date and posted transaction date for the same transaction."*.

So, you should try to work with those values to identify duplicated entries in the first place. Is there a fixed timedelta for these cases? Is there any other identifier, how you can distinguish transaction and posted transaction date? etc...
Once you can find this, you can easily refer to @e-motta 's solution, and make use of [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove them.